# Can you save a QOSM view as a GeoTiff?

Tags: openstreetmap, clip, basemap

I was wondering if you can save a certain view from QOSM to a GeoTiff?

The reason I ask is that I want to be able to clip a View into several smaller images which all border each other. For example, I have a basemap at scale 1:70000 covering part of Spain. I then need smaller but higher resolution images of this area, say at 1:10000. At the moment, I am zooming in on each area and trying to draw the outline on the 1:70000 map. There must be a simpler way!

I am using QGIS 2.14.10 - Essen.